# How to add 10 days to current time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I tried doing something like

```
Time.now + 5.days
```

but that doesn't work, even though I vaguely remember seeing, and being very impressed, with being able to do something like `2.years` etc.

How do I do that in Rails 3?

Comment: That should work.  What error are you getting?

Comment: It ahould work yes. As you're in rails, Time.zone.now sounds more appropriate

Answer (score 313, accepted):

Use

```
Time.now + 10.days
```

or even

```
10.days.from_now
```

Both definitely work. Are you sure you're in Rails and not just Ruby?

If you definitely are in Rails, where are you trying to run this from? Note that Active Support has to be loaded.

Comment: @yuval it works on rails and not ruby..Think you have got it but just to help others

Comment: There is a subtle difference. `Time.now + 10.days` always picks up your system timezone whereas `10.days.from_now` will pick up the UTC timezone if nothing is set in rails config.

Comment: Generally, it's best to use [`Time.zone.now`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones#a-summary-of-do39s-and-don39ts-with-time-zones) in place of `Time.now`.

Answer (score 24):

`days`, `years`, etc., are part of Active Support, So this won't work in `irb`, but it should work in `rails console`.

Comment: yeup - spot on. can't do this in vanilla ruby.

Comment: Works in irb as well. If you have the gem installed, just do a `require 'active_support/time'` at the beginning of the session or before you use it's commands

Answer (score 12):

This definitely works and I use this wherever I need to add days to the current date:

```
Date.today + 5
```

Answer (score 12):

Some other options, just for reference

```
-10.days.ago
# Available in Rails 4
DateTime.now.days_ago(-10)
```

Just list out all options I know:

```
[1] Time.now + 10.days
[2] 10.days.from_now
[3] -10.days.ago
[4] DateTime.now.days_ago(-10)
[5] Date.today + 10
```

So now, what is the difference between them if we care about the timezone:

- `[1, 4]` With system timezone
- `[2, 3]` With config timezone of your Rails app
- `[5]` Date only no time included in result

Answer (score 7):

Try this on Rails

```
Time.new + 10.days
```

Try this on Ruby

```
require 'date'
DateTime.now.next_day(10).to_time
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this on Ruby.
It will return a new date/time the specified number of days in the future

```
DateTime.now.days_since(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit difference between:

Time.now + 10.days

3.0.1 :003 > `Date.today + 1.day`
=> Wed, 14 Dec 2022

or even

10.days.from_now

3.0.1 :002 > `1.day.from_now`
=> 2022-12-14 15:49:57.35305172 +0600