# time created_at + 1 week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a system where users can check-in/check-out books, I want to make it so a user can keep a book for one week.

How can I do 'created_at + 1 week' for my book loan item?

At the moment I have a table like this which displays some information:
- On the 'check-in time' column I would like to add check-out time + 7 days

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Email</th>
    <th>Check-Out time</th>
    <th>Check-In time</th>
  </tr>

<% for item in @books_loaned %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.book.author %></td>
    <td><%= item.book.title %></td>
    <td><%= item.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.user.email %></td> 
    <td><%= item.created_at %></td>
    <td><%= button_to "Check-In", {:controller => :librarian, :action =>                                                                          
    :check_in}, {:method => :post} %></td>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add 10 days to current time in rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654457/how-to-add-10-days-to-current-time-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many possible ways to do this:

If you want to display only `Date` not the time then:

```
<%= item.created_at.to_date.next_week %> 
#this will add 6 days and output will be seventh day
```

or if you want to add days manually

```
<%= item.created_at.to_date+7.days %>
```

or

```
<%= item.created_at.to_date+1.week %>
```

if you also want to display time then remove `.to_date` from above code

Answer (score 1):

Simple add `7.days`

In your example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>User Email</th>
    <th>Check-Out time</th>
    <th>Check-In time</th>
  </tr>

<% for item in @books_loaned %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.book.author %></td>
    <td><%= item.book.title %></td>
    <td><%= item.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.user.email %></td> 
    <td><%= item.created_at + 7.days %></td>
    <td><%= button_to "Check-In", {:controller => :librarian, :action =>                                                                          
    :check_in}, {:method => :post} %></td>    
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

also possible `1.week` apparently. All available in Rails through ActiveSupport: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html.

Related question: [How to add 10 days to current time in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654457/how-to-add-10-days-to-current-time-in-rails)