# Rails: can one modify date attribute in model by callback? E.g.: Date.current + 1 (d + other)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a table column - valid_to, which should represent a date: 30 days from the time the entry was saved into database. 
But how can I do such a thing in model?
E.g. in controller I can do such thing this way:

```
@baby = baby.create(baby_params.
        merge( :valid_to => DateTime.current + 30 )
```

In view I can use hidden field in the form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :valid_to => DateTime.current + 30 %>
```

so is there a way to do such a thing in model? I tried defining self.valid_to before_validation but for no avail: in irb my valid_to column is just nil. To add: I store it as datetime not string.

**UPDATE**

solution in the end was:

```
before_validation :set_valid_to, :on => :create

def set_valid_to
  self[:valid_to] = 30.days.from_now
end
```

and lived this thing in module, but that's another story...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654457/how-to-add-10-days-to-current-time-in-rails

Comment: @Brad, sorry if I was way-out in my wording, but by mentioning irb, I meant observing my db entries in console, calling Baby.all, not calculating. That question as it's answers didn't help solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work if you only want it done on initial record creation. If you want it updated every time it's saved use `before_save` instead of `before_create`.

```
class Baby < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_valid_to

  private

  def set_valid_to
    self.valid_to = 30.days.from_now
  end
end
```

Comment: hm...so it appears "from_now" works where "+" don't. Strange. Thanks!

Comment: Well it might have been. `DateTime + 30` is going to add 30 seconds, not 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

in irb:

```
@baby = baby.create
@baby.valid_to = Time.now + 30.days
@baby.save
```